# Partial string filter pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

On Pandas 1.3.4 and Python 3.9.

So I'm having issues filtering for a partial piece of the string. The "Date" column is listed in the format of MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS A/PM where the most recent one is on top. If the date is single digit (example: November 3rd), it does not have the 0 such that it is 11/3 instead of 11/03. Basically I'm looking to go look at column named "Date" and have python read parts of the string to filter for only today.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcqSv.png) is what the original csv looks like. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Dquh.png) is what I want to do to the file. Basically looking for a specific date but not any time of that date and implement the =RIGHT() formula. However [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAqrs.png) is what I end up with with the following code.

```
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv(r'file.csv', dtype=str)

today = date.today()
d1 = today.strftime("%m/%#d/%Y")  # to find out what today is

df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['New Phone', 'Phone number', 'Date'])
df['New Phone'] = df['Phone number'].str[-10:]

df_today = df['Date'].str.contains(f'{d1}',case=False, na=False)

df_today.to_csv(r'file.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: You set df_today to the results of your filter, instead you want to save the value of df_today if the results of the filter is true. Contains returns true/false if the rows are matching.

Comment: Why don't you convert your datetime column to datetime type, e.g.`df = pd.read_csv(..., parse_dates=['Date'])`? Then you can do, e.g. `df[df.Date.dt.normalize()=='2021-11-03']`.

Comment: I've got a solution, but @FinestRyeBread, what are the possible formats for the Date columns? are they all consistent?

Comment: @user17242583 they're all consistent in the format of MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM so they'll follow the format of something like 11/8/2021 3:31:00 PM or 11/20/2021 3:31:00 PM

Comment: `df=df.assign(NewPhone=df['Phone number'].str[-10:])`#Create new column

`df[df['date']==pd.Timestamp.today().date().strftime("%m/%d/%Y") ]`# filter out dates that are not today

Comment: @FinestRyeBread does it matter if the time part of the dates are truncated off?

Comment: @user17242583 the time part I don't really need python to parse, as I'm just trying to look at all of the phone numbers during the whole day; so if it just shows 11/8/2021 then that's all I need

Comment: @wwnde it does do the RIGHT() function however it's still not filtering for today's date

Comment: @FinestRyeBread coerce df['date'] to datetime, it possibly aint doing it because they are in different formats. Are you able to copy paste the text and not image so that the forum can reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```py
df_today = df['Date'].str.contains(f'{d1}',case=False, na=False)
```

All you're doing there is creating a *mask*; essentially what that is is just a Pandas series, containg `True` or `False` in each row, according to the condition you created the mask in. The spreadsheet get's only `FALSE` as you showed because non of the items in the `Date` contain the string that the variable `d1` holds...

Instead, try this:

```py
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd

# Load the CSV file, and change around the columns
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(r'file.csv', dtype=str), columns=['New Phone', 'Phone number', 'Date'])

# Take the last ten chars of each phone number
df['New Phone'] = df['Phone number'].str[-10:]

# Convert each date string to a pd.Timestamp, removing the time
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str.split(r'\s+', n=1).str[0])

# Get the phone numbers that are from today
df_today = df[df['Date'] == date.today().strftime('%m/%d/%Y')]

# Write the result to the CSV file
df_today.to_csv(r'file.csv', index=False)
```